# Find the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a semicircle of radius 2.

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, derivatives, optimization

I already know how to do this problem, but I have a question on a small part of the solution. This is an example out of Thomas' Calculus. I included the solution from the text below, and I'm wondering about the fact that the domain of $A(x)$ is $[0, 2].$ Wouldn't an $x$-value of $0$ or $2$ give a rectangle that is just a line, which wouldn't be a rectangle at all? Wouldn't this contradict the premise that we're looking for the largest "rectangle" that can be inscribed in a semicircle of radius $2?$ I feel like the domain should be $(0, 2).$ I know that this wouldn't change the answer at all, but it still bothers me, and it comes up all the time with these kinds of problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you impose that a rectangle must have width and length greater than $0$, then your argument can be used to prove that there is no *smallest* rectangle in the given conditions. But since that restriction has no effect if we are searching for the largest rectangle, why bother?

Answer (score 0):

You include the endpoints and the critical points and compare the areas to find the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum. While the result is obvious in this particular example, it is a good practice to go through all the steps to show the procedure in general.

Answer (score 0):

Such examples use closed intervals because as long as $A(x)$ (or whatever you're trying to maximize) is defined everywhere and is continuous on the interval, it has a maximum value in the interval.

If you were just doing $x \in (0,2),$ it's conceivable that for some way of generating shapes with that parameter, there's a local maximum at $x = 1,$ but $A(0.1) > A(1),$
$A(0.01) > A(0.1),$ etc. with no value of $x$ where $A(x)$ matches or exceeds all other values of $A(x).$

But if you decided that instead of looking only at *non-degenerate* rectangles (the kind that have two dimensions and seem to you to be legitimate rectangles), you will look at this class of shapes that include some line segments (produced when $x=0$ or $x=2$) as well as non-degenerate rectangles. And you find the maximum value of $A(x)$ on this entire set. And it turns out that this maximum occurs at a value of $x$ that produces a non-degenerate rectangle, not just a line segment.
Well, if that rectangle was bigger than all the other rectangles *and* the line segments, it's certainly bigger than all the other rectangles, and you have your answer.

You *could* do the job just looking at $(0,2)$ but then you have to prove that there isn't any funny stuff going on near either end of the interval that prevents there from being a maximum value.